# Shortcuts to computing state vectors of spin states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am working through Quantum Mechanics: the Theoretical Minimum and am finding questions such as representing spin states such as $|l \rangle$ $|r \rangle$ $|i \rangle$ $|o \rangle$, in terms of $|u \rangle$ and $|d \rangle$, very time consuming  .

For example:
$|r \rangle = \frac {1}{\sqrt2} |u \rangle + \frac {1}{\sqrt2} |d \rangle$

Once I have got past the first 2 kets, $|r \rangle$ and $|l \rangle$, computing the last two kets, $|i \rangle$ and $|o \rangle$, has a very lengthy process (though doable) due to the number of inner product statements that have to be expanded to find the values probability amplitudes* **. Is there any way to make this quicker/ more efficiant or is it just practice?

*such as:
$ \langle l|u\rangle = \frac {1}{2}$

**I may be incorrectly refering to probability amplitude, in the example:

$\langle r| = \frac {1}{\sqrt2} \langle u| + \frac {1}{\sqrt2} \langle d|$

The probability amplitudes would be $\frac {1}{\sqrt2}$ .

Edit, notation:

The kets $|l \rangle$ $|r \rangle$ $|i \rangle$ $|o \rangle$ are the state vectors for spin in their respective dimensions. E.g: $|l \rangle$ is the state vector for spin = -1 when measured in the x unit vector direction. Whereas $|u \rangle$ is the state vector for spin = +1 when measured in the z unit vector direction.

Comment: Welcome to SE. It'd be best if you explained your notations. I studied spin, I get a general idea of where this is coming from, but I'm still not sure here.

Comment: The shortcut is to use tables or software like Mathematica where these are encoded as built-in functions.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero thanks for the help